# Using YouTube data api within chrome extension embedded iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am trying to create a chrome extension that adds an iframe to an existing website and populates it with data from the YouTube data api however I am having trouble with restrictions imposed by the chrome extension content policy.
My current issue comes from user login, I need to use the gapi to get the users OAuth2 key however it appears that [gapi isn't supported within sandboxed environments](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js#supported-environments). Is it possible to use the YouTube data api without gapi? Or more directly is it possible have the code below work inside an iframe placed there by a chrome extension? This example comes from the [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

```
<html><head><title>Google APIs - Sample JS Page</title></head>
<body>

<script>

  /***** START BOILERPLATE CODE: Load client library, authorize user. *****/

  // Global variables for GoogleAuth object, auth status.
  var GoogleAuth;

  /**
   * Load the API's client and auth2 modules.
   * Call the initClient function after the modules load.
   */
  function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
  }

  function initClient() {
    // Initialize the gapi.client object, which app uses to make API requests.
    // Get API key and client ID from API Console.
    // 'scope' field specifies space-delimited list of access scopes

    gapi.client.init({
        'clientId': 'REPLACE_ME',
        'discoveryDocs': ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest'],
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner'
    }).then(function () {
      GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

      // Handle initial sign-in state. (Determine if user is already signed in.)
      setSigninStatus();

      // Call handleAuthClick function when user clicks on "Authorize" button.
      $('#execute-request-button').click(function() {
        handleAuthClick(event);
      }); 
    });
  }

  function handleAuthClick(event) {
    // Sign user in after click on auth button.
    GoogleAuth.signIn();
  }

  function setSigninStatus() {
    var user = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
    isAuthorized = user.hasGrantedScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner');
    // Toggle button text and displayed statement based on current auth status.
    if (isAuthorized) {
      defineRequest();
    }
  }

  function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    setSigninStatus();
  }

  function createResource(properties) {
    var resource = {};
    var normalizedProps = properties;
    for (var p in properties) {
      var value = properties[p];
      if (p && p.substr(-2, 2) == '[]') {
        var adjustedName = p.replace('[]', '');
        if (value) {
          normalizedProps[adjustedName] = value.split(',');
        }
        delete normalizedProps[p];
      }
    }
    for (var p in normalizedProps) {
      // Leave properties that don't have values out of inserted resource.
      if (normalizedProps.hasOwnProperty(p) && normalizedProps[p]) {
        var propArray = p.split('.');
        var ref = resource;
        for (var pa = 0; pa < propArray.length; pa++) {
          var key = propArray[pa];
          if (pa == propArray.length - 1) {
            ref[key] = normalizedProps[p];
          } else {
            ref = ref[key] = ref[key] || {};
          }
        }
      };
    }
    return resource;
  }

  function removeEmptyParams(params) {
    for (var p in params) {
      if (!params[p] || params[p] == 'undefined') {
        delete params[p];
      }
    }
    return params;
  }

  function executeRequest(request) {
    request.execute(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }

  function buildApiRequest(requestMethod, path, params, properties) {
    params = removeEmptyParams(params);
    var request;
    if (properties) {
      var resource = createResource(properties);
      request = gapi.client.request({
          'body': resource,
          'method': requestMethod,
          'path': path,
          'params': params
      });
    } else {
      request = gapi.client.request({
          'method': requestMethod,
          'path': path,
          'params': params
      });
    }
    executeRequest(request);
  }

  /***** END BOILERPLATE CODE *****/


  function defineRequest() {
    // See full sample for buildApiRequest() code, which is not 
// specific to a particular API or API method.

buildApiRequest('GET',
                '/youtube/v3/search',
                {'maxResults': '25',
                 'part': 'snippet',
                 'q': 'surfing',
                 'type': ''});

  }
</script>

<button id="execute-request-button">Authorize</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" 
        onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()" 
        onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
</body></html>
```

I will refrain from posting any of my code as it's a total mess and will just confuse anybody who reads it. I also can't help but feel I am going in the wrong direction.
Any pointers as to how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Move all inline javascript code into a .js file and include it using the `<script src="js-file-path" ></script>`

Comment: I tried that however I have no idea how I would convert the "async defer" bindings at the bottom to js as you can't do that with the chrome content policy and it does nothing to get around gapi not being supported.